# XVFB, Debian Wheezy, and x-ttcidfont-conf

Tags: debian, phantomjs, xvfb

I am trying to screencapture some non-us (Chinese, Russian, etc.) sites using Selenium with PhantomJS via Python running on Debian Wheezy.

When I screencapture non-us sites, the characters show up as little boxes (screenshot attached). Images and western letters render properly.

I think the problem is that PhantomJS is running on XVFB and XVFB is looking for some depreciated true type fonts. These can be found in a package called x-ttcidfont-conf. The problem is I can't install this package on Wheezy. When I try the following: "sudo apt-get install x-ttcidfont-conf", I get the following: "Package x-ttcidfont-conf is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'x-ttcidfont-conf' has no installation candidate"

Looks like the x-ttcidfont also depends on a deprecated "Deforma" font manager.

Other XVFB font issues were successfully resolved with "sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic".

How can I get the x-ttcid-font either installed on Wheezy or change xvfb so that it renders Chinese type characters correctly?!

Comment: What about `xfonts-intl-chinese` or `xfonts-intl-chinese-big`?

Comment: Installed them, but it didn't work. I think it is something where xvfb is specifically looking for the x-ttcidfont-conf. I can't figure out how to change where/what it is looking for.

Comment: I have determined the issue is NOT with XVFB. Phantom does not require XVFB to work. The issue is somehow with Phantom.